# How to send image from within a scrollView to "detailViewController"?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, tableview

I have a scrollView inside my tableView. My scrollview has pageEnabled = true with UIImage/UIImageView varying from 1 to 3 within them.

I also have Page Control associated with the CurrentPage which works. I'm trying to associate my CurrentPage so the correct image so send to my detailViewController

Here's my following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell: FriendsFeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! FriendsFeedTableViewCell

//images array will vary 1-3: as of now
let images = masterImageArray[indexPath.row]

let scrollView = cell.imageScrollView
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
scrollView.tag = indexPath.row

var imageViews = [UIImageView]()
imageViews.append(cell.imageView_1)
imageViews.append(cell.imageView_2)
imageViews.append(cell.imageView_3)

cell.imageView_1.hidden = true
cell.imageView_2.hidden = true
cell.imageView_3.hidden = true

for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++ {
    imageViews[i].image = images[i]
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 310 * (i + 1), height: 400)
    cell.pageControl.numberOfPages = (i + 1) // tells how many pages
    imageViews[i].hidden = false
}

//button: Tells which image in indexPath we want to view
cell.tapToViewButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.tapToViewButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

return cell
}
```

TableViewCell:

```
class FriendsFeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) { //current page: works
    let currentPage = (CGFloat(imageScrollView.contentOffset.x) / CGFloat(userImageView!.frame.size.width))
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
}
```

//Button and Segue: to know which image to send

```
var imageSenderTag: Int()

func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){ // which image we want to view
imageSenderTag = sender.tag
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toViewImageVC", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if (segue.identifier == "toViewImageVC"){
    let viewImageVC: ViewImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewImageViewController
 //curent page of scrollview so send over to new VC
}
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to send the current image over to new the new ViewController.

I have that UIImage array inside the cellForRow function which i don't know how to access cause it's local. Also the current page is in the TableViewCell file so I not sure how to pass the "currentPage" to the tableViewContoller file.

What's the best way to approach this problem. I think maybe I should add all my code that deals withe scrollView inside my tableViewCell File.

Comment: did you tried images[imageSenderTag] in the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: imageSenderTag records the indexPath.row which only tells what index the user is currently on. Lets say, row 24 so If I use images[imageSenderTag] (which is images[24]) will crash because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the cell in the prepareForSegue-method to get the current Index of your pageControl. Now you have the imageSenderTag-index to get the right imagesArray from your masterImageArray and you have the currentImageIndex to get the right image from your imagesArray. Your prepareForSegue-method should look quite similar to this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toViewImageVC"){
        let viewImageVC: ViewImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewImageViewController
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(index: imageSenderTag);
        let cell: FriendsFeedTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FriendsFeedTableViewCell
        let currentImageIndex = cell.pageControl.currentPage
        let images = masterImageArray[imageSenderTag]
        let currentImage = images[currentImageIndex]
        viewImageVC.imageView.image = currentImage
    }
}
```

Notice: This is a fast and hacky approach, because the tableview recreates the cell again in the prepareForSegue-method. A better solution would be by creating a custom delegate- or observer-protocol, so the cell can tell if the current image changes to his observers.